# Sync two mongodb databases from different locations programmatically

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a web application (using MongoDB database, AngularJS on front-end and NodeJS on back-end) that deployed on 2 places. First is on static ip so that it can access from anywhere and second is on one local machine so that user can use it when the internet connection is not available. So on both places, data can be inserted by user. My requirement is to sync the both databases, when internet connection is available on local machine i.e. from local system database to remote system database and vice-versa without loosing any data on both places.

One way I am thinking about is provide the sync button in the application and sync the databases using insert/update query. I am not sure is there any better and automated way to do this task so that the databases sync automatically like data copied in replica set.

Please provide the best solution to do this task. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yeah, there are no built-in mechanisms to do this. So it's on you. BTW, how are you planning to resolve conflicts (the same documents is updated in both databases with different values)?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Actually I have 2 collections that primarily need to sync. In one collection, data can be inserted only through a web application form, and that values never updated. So conflict issue will not come there. In 2nd collection, there can be conflicts, but in that case I will give the priority of the values that exist on the static ip and override the local changes.
So I decided to do it using my own logic. Thanks to all for your time and comments.